# Creating a List Using Excel Formulas

Tags: excel, function

I'm trying to create a formula in Excel that looks across a range of cells for a particular number (1-5) and then inputs the contents of another cell.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
Minnesota          Iowa          Oklahoma          California          Arizona
3                  2             5                 4                   1
```

I'd like to have a formula that looks across the row with the numbers for "1" and then inputs the state name above it.

Thanks for your help!!!!

Answer (score 1):

.If your numbers, 3 2 5 4 1, are in Row 2, you can find where the "1" is with the following formula:

```
=MATCH(1,2:2,FALSE)
```

You can replace the first "1" with a cell address containing the number you're looking for if you want, and you can limit the second term to certain columns, e.g. A2:E2. The FALSE in the third term means you want an exact match.

For the above problem, the MATCH function returns the number 5, i.e. it's in the fifth cell of 3 2 5 4 1.

With this result, you can find a cell in a range with the Index function like so:

```
=INDEX(1:1,MATCH(1,2:2,FALSE))
```

Again, you can put something like A1:E1 instead of 1:1.

Alternately, if you always want the cell above but it won't necessarily be in row 1, you can use:

```
=OFFSET(A2,-1,MATCH(1,2:2,FALSE)-1)
```